# How to get thc-hydra to work from homebrew installation?

Tags: macos, ssh, homebrew, brute-force

I've installed thc-hydra (brute force tool) on my OS X machine using:

```
brew install hydra
```

But when trying to hack the ssh password on my server I get the following error message:

```
[ERROR] Compiled without LIBSSH v0.4.x support, module is not available!
```

How do I get around this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`brew info hydra` shows:

```
hydra: stable 8.1 (bottled), HEAD
https://www.thc.org/thc-hydra/
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/hydra.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: pkg-config ✔
Required: openssl ✔
Optional: subversion ✘, libidn ✘, libssh ✘, pcre ✔, gtk+ ✔
==> Options
--with-gtk+
    Build with gtk+ support
--with-libidn
    Build with libidn support
--with-libssh
    Build with libssh support
--with-pcre
    Build with pcre support
--with-subversion
    Build with subversion support
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
```

To allow ssh support, install using command:

```
brew install hydra --with-libssh
```

It is always a good idea to use `brew info` before running `brew install`